# Using one .cls file in Overleaf for multiple projects

Tags: overleaf

Is it possible to have one master .cls file in Overleaf that works across different projects? For example, if I make a change in the .cls file while working in one project, it will be updated in all of the other projects that use that .cls file?

I know that I could import the .cls file from another project, but I cannot update it within the project that has imported it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is an Overleaf specific question and is best asked to their support team who are quick to respond, this is trivial on a local installation but not sure about Overleaf

Comment: Welcome! Clearly a question for Overleaf support, but I fear it's not possible; each overleaf project is run in a separate container, I think...

Comment: @Rmano, gotcha, yeah it doesn't seem possible, but I'll reach out to Overleaf if I really need to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share files across projects in Overleaf using the **New File** > **From another project** option as described here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Can_I_share_files_(e.g._.bib_and_some_graphics)_across_my_projects%3F

The file appears as a read-only file in the target project. Changes to the file in the original can be pulled in to the projects it is shared with by pressing the Refresh button in the file.

If you need the (now different) .cls files to be edited in each project, then an option would be to create a project that you use as a template when starting other projects. Copy the original source project to make new projects: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Copying_a_project

As mentioned in the comments, questions like this are best sent to Overleaf support. You can reach them here: https://www.overleaf.com/contact or via support@overleaf.com.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution I could think of myself and I haven't really tried it for an extended period of time, so I'll give it a go and see how well it works.